# How to replace MapView with separate Pins?

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, prism, mapsui

I'm trying to change MapView in my Xamarin Forms app (with Mapsui and Prism), as I need separate view to store Pins. First MapView (let's call it `default`) is for displaying all pins from list. Second MapView (`history`) is for displaying new pins, which are removed when leaving Page.

I have `Dictionary` for storing my MapViews to have easy way to access any view I want. Every created MapView has **the same instance of Map**. I want to change from `default` to `history` which should hide pins that are added in `default` view.

I change view with this:

```
public void ChangeView(string name)
        {
            var prev = MapView;
            loggerService.Info($"Pins: {prev.Pins.Count}");
            MapView = GetView(name); // Current MapView in XAML, returns instance of MapView
            loggerService.Info($"New view pins: {MapView.Pins.Count}");

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
            {
                Task.Delay(2000).Wait();

                loggerService.Info($"View pins: {MapView.Pins.Count}");
            });

            MapView.Refresh();
        }
```

extra code with log is for debugging purposes - it shows correct values (prev pins = 7, new pins = 0, view pins = 0).

I've added `history` view without Zoom buttons to make sure it is changing - and it is (so there is no need to post XAML, I think).

How should I change MapView to hide pins when navigating to history and show them when I switch back to default view?
Or is there a better way to 'group' Pins and hide/show them basing on name?

**Update**
I think this may be important to mention:

```
public Pin AddMarker(Position point)
        {
            var pin = new Pin(MapView)
            {
                Label = "PinType.Pin",
                Position = point,
                Type = PinType.Pin,
                Transparency = 0.5f,
                Color = Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromRgb(2, 144, 210),
                Scale = 0.5f,
            };

            MapView.Pins.Add(pin);

            return pin;
        }
```

This is the way I add Pins to view. This is the same MapView as above (all the code is from `MapService`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some options

- Perhaps you can bind the IsVisible property of the Pins to a HistoryMode field on your view. I never used this myself.
- Use some of the lower level functionality. Like

  - Use separate layers for default and history and enable/disable them when needed. You might need to do the conversion of WGS84 (gps coordinates) to SphericalMercator. https://mapsui.com/api/Mapsui.Projection.SphericalMercator.html?q=sphericalmercator
  - Use a ThemeStyle. It has a method that can be use to specify any style you need (visible/color/symbol) based and the feature attributes. https://mapsui.com/api/Mapsui.Styles.Thematics.ThemeStyle.html?q=themestyle

For the lower level functionality you may need to the samples to get you on your way: https://mapsui.com/documentation/samples.html

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I think the separate layer is the most suitable for my case. But how am I able to hide pins from layer? As I can see, PointsSample covers "points" as bitmap, not built in Pins feature, am I right?

Comment: I dived in MapView code and found out that `Pins` is nothing than predefined layer with `ObservableCollectionProvider` containing Pins. I think I will figure the rest out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is always an option to copy the MapView code to your own project and modify it to your needs.

Comment: Finally I've changed switching MapViews to switching Layers. Now it's working as expected.